# Декодирование данных типа form-urlencoded во многовложенный обьект python?

Tags: python, django, http, кодировка

На бэк джанги приходят данные в формате application/x-www-form-urlencoded. В таком виде:

```
{'leads[update][0][id]': ['55316135'], 'leads[update][0][name]': ['веб-хук тест 2']}
```

Отправитель данных  - приложение на php, на него влиять нет возможности. Как корректно распарсить средствами python эти данные не потеряв стуктуру и вложенности?

Comment: literal_eval?..

Comment: Какого вида структура должна в итоге получиться? update, id, name - это имена ключей или имена переменных?

Comment: А о каком php-приложении речь? Оно сделано на каком-нибудь php-фреймворке? Это может помочь узнать детали устройства этого формата

Comment: А вот для javascript существует библиотека для работы с таким форматом: https://github.com/ljharb/qs Остаётся найти такую же или написать для python

Comment: А вот и нашёл собсна, правда декодирует немного иначе https://github.com/bernii/querystring-parser

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо - помог